# How to revert back previous data of a user in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Hi I am working in drupal 7 where when a user updating a profile i need to call a .Net service which will update another database tables fields , If update is done properly it returns `True` if not it returns `False` . Now I call this service within this function

```
function user_verify_profile_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
 $account = $form_state['user'];
}
```

Now the problem is that if the service return me false how do I revert the drupal user data to his previous data so that I it works perfectly. Otherwise drupal database is updating but the database related to that service could not.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you are querying your external service in the submit hook of the profile form. In this step, drupal internals had already updated the database. This is no drupal problem, this is by design of your code.

I would suggest that you do not tie the external service to a submit hook and use some kind of queue to create a "profile update" task with the new data and store the old user data away. In addition mark the user as "update on external pending" so that no other changes could be done.